# Warning: mysqli::__construct(): MYSQLI in PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am not really familiar with mysqli that much, and I have to upgrade my script to mysqli, please could you help me sort it?

Code Below:

```
    function getConnected($host,$db_user,$db_password,$db) {

       $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db);

       if($mysqli->connect_error) 
         die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

       return $mysqli;
    }
    $mysqli = getConnected("localhost", "root", " ", "test");
```

Comment: what you need.. Explain the problem/ issue clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything worng with your code except that you are mixing Object oriented and procedural style. (not that i think it's would be a reason to fail)

Simply change this:

```
die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
```

to this

```
die('Connect Error (' . mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. mysqli->connect_error);
```

and you are all set in OOP.

---

After this you should be able to do thing like http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

```
$mysqli = getConnected("localhost", "root", " ", "test");
$mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM tableA');
```

or even

```
getConnected("localhost", "root", " ", "test")->query('SELECT * FROM tableA');
```

---

or start a statement http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php . Is now good practice to implement a prepared statement (mandatory if you handle user inputs). It basically replacing the escaping.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close(); }
```

It's a bit of a learning curve to upgrade to mysqli but once you got the hang of it you will see how robust it is compared to its predecessor.